# Most efficient way to map object properties to dictionary where keys represent path using extension method

Tags: c#, reflection

What is the most efficient way for an extension method to map object properties to a IDictionary where :

- keys are property paths (e.g. "Customer.Company.Address.Line1")
- values are string representation of the property values (e.g. "123
  Main St." or "" (empty string) when null or default value)
- collection of properties still only contain path (e.g.
  public IList Invoices --> "Customer.Invoices" but value is
  collection count)

Is use of reflection best approach?
Is there an example?

Thanks
Z...

### Clarification Updates

- dictionary keys should be paths based on property names not type hierarchy.So if a Customer has property `public Company ParentCompany` and Company has property `public Address BillingAddress` then the key path should be "ParentCompany.BillingAddress"

Comment: you want the complete "property tree" for an instance ?

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward reflection exercise.  You should just try to implement this yourself and come back to SO if you have more specific questions.  (and most likely, such individual questions, such as "How to get the list of properties for an object?", "How do I get a property's value through reflection?" etc. have already been answered.)

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to know if there were more efficient methods than reflection (it looks like he already knows about that approach).

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus yes a flattened "property tree"

Comment: @ananthonline, if he already understood that approach, I would assume the OP wouldn't be asking us to supply him an example then, no?

Comment: @ Kirk Woll My primary question was "Most efficient....extension method...."

Comment: @Kirk Woll the example asked was for both most efficient reflection approach but also, if it exists, most efficient non-reflection based approach.

Comment: Are Customer, Company, Address (well all the "complex properties" you need) in the same assembly, or deriving from the same base class, or another way to distinguish them ?

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus they are in the same assembly, but I need other properties ("non complex") as well. For example int Age, or string FirstName...So entries would be "Customer.Age", "25" and "Customer.FirstName", "Jonh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetProperties<T>(this T obj)
    where T : class
{
    var properties = obj.GetPropertyList();
    return properties.ToDictionary(prop => prop.Item1, prop => prop.Item2);
}

public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetPropertyList<T>(this T obj)
    where T : class
{
    if (obj == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");

    Type t = obj.GetType();

    return GetProperties(obj, t, t.Name);
}

private static IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string>> GetProperties(object obj, Type objType, string propertyPath)
{
    // If atomic property, return property value with path to property
    if (objType.IsValueType || objType.Equals(typeof(string)))
        return Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(propertyPath, obj.ToString()), 1);

    else
    {
        // Return empty value for null values
        if (obj == null)
            return Enumerable.Repeat(Tuple.Create(propertyPath, string.Empty), 1);

        else
        {
            // Recursively examine properties; add properties to property path
            return from prop in objType.GetProperties()
                   where prop.CanRead && !prop.GetIndexParameters().Any()
                   let propValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null)
                   let propType = prop.PropertyType
                   from nameValPair in GetProperties(propValue, propType, string.Format("{0}.{1}", propertyPath, prop.Name))
                   select nameValPair;
        }
    }
}
```

This still doesn't handle default values on value parameters. Note that the logic for when to stop recursively iterating is key. Originally I stopped at properties of value types, but that meant that strings were treated like other objects. So I added a special case to treat strings as an atomic type.

Comment: You'll have to adjust for your use case. For example, prop.Name needs to include the class name as well.

Comment: On second thought, if you want to include the whole parent type hierarchy in the name field, you should use recursion. Is the name field built using type hierarchy or composition?